# Bash processing pipeline produces more lines than input

Tags: bash

I am looking up the output of `fdupes` in a database dump:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a a
  do for i in "${a[@]}"
    do 
      fid=$(grep -F "${i//\.\//public://}" file_managed.dump.txt|cut -d'(' -f2 |cut -d, -f1| sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
      echo -n "${fid:-$i}" $'\t'
    done
    echo
  done < dupes.log  > fids_dupes.txt
```

and for some reason I am getting more than one line in the output than the input:

```
 wc -l dupes.log fids_dupes.txt
   3968 dupes.log
  12358 fids_dupes.txt
```

I thought because of the `echo -n` / `echo` I would be getting only one. Manual comparison of the file is not a revelation either. What am I doing wrong? (Aside from not using a real programming language to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you assumed that the `grep` command always finds at most one match. But if it finds multiple matches in `file_managed.dump.txt`, then each of those will result in a new line. The linebreaks will be stored inside `fid` and `echo -n` will print those linebreaks too (it just doesn't add a linebreak at the end).
You can test this theory by limiting to one match using `grep -m1`.  If that results in an equal line count, you can post a minimal example of your input files and expected output, so that we can help you come up with a better solution that avoids false-positives / duplicates.

Although less likely than above scenario, there is also a chance that `$i` contains the literal substring `\n` (`backslash` + `n`) and your `echo` is interpreting escape sequences. If that would be the case, you could fix it by using `printf %s\\t "${fid:-$i}"` instead.

Comment: `$fid` can not contain `\n` , `sed 's/[^0-9]//g'` removes everything that is not a digit, doesn't it? But yes, `grep -m1` does work. I posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/76289555/308851 as a followup.

Comment: @chx Oh right, thanks for the hint. Indeed, `$fid`  cannot contain a literal `\n` (`backslash` + `n`)  because of the `sed`. I corrected that part. However, (*You already know this. I just want to clear possible misunderstands for other readers*):  `$i` can still contain a literal `\n` (`backslash` + `n`). And both `$i` and `$fid` can contain literal linebreaks, because `sed` only processes characters in each line, but not the linebreaks themselves.